# How to bind a CFC directly to a select menu?

Tags: ajax, binding, coldfusion, cfc

I'm trying to create a select menu where one can select a department and then select employees in that department. Related Selects...

Ok here is the problem...I need to bind directly to the cfc because binding like this:

```
<cfselect name="people" bind = "cfc:test.getPeople({department.value})" />
```

DOES **NOT** WORK. It does nothing... here is what deparment looks like:

```
<cfselect name="department"
        query="getDepartments"
        display="deptname"
        value="deptcode" 
        queryPosition = "below">
        <option value = "">Select a Department</option>
        </cfselect>
```

and here the cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cfset THIS.dsn="sqlProd_faculty_db">


    <!--- Get art by media type --->
    <cffunction name="getPeople" access="remote" returnType="query" >
        <cfargument name="dcode" type="any" required="true">

        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var data="">


        <!--- Get data --->
        <cfquery name="data" datasource="#THIS.dsn#">
        SELECT  b.LastName + ', ' + b.FirstName AS FullName, p.IDNum FROM faculty.dbo.SACS_Person p, faculty.dbo.budPerson 
      b WHERE p.DeptCode = '#arguments.dcode#' AND p.IDNum = b.ID ORDER BY b.LastName, 
        b.FirstName
        </cfquery>


        <!--- And return it --->
        <cfreturn data>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
<cfselect name="people"
        bind = "url:test.cfc?method=getPeople&returnFormat=json&dcode={department.value}" 
        display = "FullName" value = "IDNum"
        BindOnLoad = "true" />
```

But that didn't work... get a parsing error..

```
Error parsing JSON response: 



<script language="javascript">

<!--

document.onkeydown = catchKey;

step1 = 0;

step2 = 0;



function catchKey(e){

   if(window.event.keyCode == 17){

      step1 = 1;

   }

   if(window.event.keyCode == 18){

      step2 = 1;

   }

   if(window.event.keyCode == 65){

      if(step1 && step2){

         newLevel = prompt("Level:", "new Level");

         step1 = 0; step2 = 0;

         gotostring = "./admin_macros.cfm?NewLevel=" + newLevel + "&Action=LevelChange";

         window.location = gotostring;

      }

   }

}

-->

</script>

{"COLUMNS":["FULLNAME","IDNUM"],"DATA":[]} [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information]
```

Comment: ignore the dipslay and values part.. i know that is wrong ... i just want to know how to bind directly.. like how is it suppose to look ?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question and perhaps take out the parts that you mention to ignore? That might make the question a bit clearer. Also I presume you <cfselect> is inside the a <cfform>? Finally is your CFC in the same directory as your CFM file?

Comment: why use url: instead of cfc: ? did cfc: not work for u?

Comment: what is "DOES WORK. It does nothing" ?? Does it work or not? :S

Comment: Ok rephrased it :) sorry some typos ; ; it doesn't work, but it should. I think it has something to do with the way my IT department has our CF set up. Yes my CFC is in the same directory and yes the cfselects are in a <cfform> i didn't include that cause I figured it would be obvious. ><;;

Comment: also the department select is coming from a query that is on the same page as it... ><;

Comment: try just {department} , I don't think u need the dot-value

Comment: "Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information", try that.  You using Firebug already right?

Comment: i tried "enabling debugging" but ?cfdebug doesn't do anything.. :\

Comment: you should get popup-like window with js exceptions written there. in most cases they are good enough to track the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The form does not have the department.value defined unless it is submitted and hence your bind will not work. Please have your second cfselect(employee) placed in a cflayout and have in your onchange event of the 'department' cfselect to submit the form to the layout. You can use the coldFusio.navigate() method to submit your depart ment form onto the employee layout.